# How to use xr.apply_ufunc with changing dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I have a climate dataset with 3 dimensions loaded with xarray

```
climate = xr.open_dataset(data_file)
climate
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 621, lon: 1405, time: 424)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-11-01 2017-11-02 2017-11-03 ...
  * lon      (lon) float64 -125.0 -125.0 -124.9 -124.9 -124.8 -124.8 -124.7 ...
  * lat      (lat) float64 49.92 49.87 49.83 49.79 49.75 49.71 49.67 49.62 ...
Data variables:
  tmean    (time, lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
  status   (time) object 'provisional' 'provisional' 'provisional' ...
```

I have a model which gets applied to the time dimension, and returns a 2d array of just the lat,lon.

```
apply_model(climate.tmean.values).shape
(621, 1405)
```

How can I use this within `xr.apply_ufunc()`? I've tried several different things but it always complains of some dimension error.

For example:

```
def apply_model_ufunc(climate):
    return xr.apply_ufunc(
            apply_model, climate,
            input_core_dims=[['lat','lon']])

apply_model_ufunc(climate)
ValueError: dimensions ('time',) must have the same length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=2
```

Or

```
def apply_model_ufunc(climate):
    return xr.apply_ufunc(
            apply_model, climate,
            input_core_dims=[['time','lat','lon']],
            output_core_dims=[['lat','lon']])

apply_model_ufunc(climate)
ValueError: operand to apply_ufunc has required core dimensions ['time', 'lat', 'lon'], but some of these are missing on the input variable:  ['lat', 'lon']
```

Comment: Can you please share what your full input Dataset looks like?

Comment: I added the output from calling the dataset directly

Comment: [docs.xarray examples/apply_ufunc_vectorize_1d](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/apply_ufunc_vectorize_1d.html), in 2023: "We will iteratively build up the
        right set of arguments to apply_ufunc and read through many error messages in doing so."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more fiddling I think I figured out out. The issue was `apply_ufunc` will apply the function over all data variables. The "status" variable in my dataset was causing issues as it only has the time dimension. The working code was

```
def apply_model_ufunc(climate):
    return xr.apply_ufunc(
            apply_model, climate,
            input_core_dims=[['time']],
            output_dtypes=[float])

apply_model_ufunc(climate['tmean'])
```